# Magento 404 error on language store specific URLs

Tags: magento

I have a magento(enterprise) site with 2 language stores. Each having their own dedicated url to a given item or resource be it a static page or a product page.

I am using the URL rules via the CMS to manage my SEF URLs for all resources.

The problem is the following scenario:

1. Site defaults to LANG #1.
2. When user switches from LANG#1 to LANG#2, switch happens with no issues - content switches to specific lang (_store=lang">http://www.sitename.com/?_store=lang)
3. But regardless of what lang store I am in, if I have enter a url from the other lang store into my current language store, I get a 404 error.

What I want the system checking the current store for the resource requested. If not found it should route to the next store and check for the resource in there. If found, store should switch to the lang store the item was found and url redirected.

What class should I extend in order to achieve this ( i am quite new to magento).

I went as far as inspecting if I can extend this class to do what I want: /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Url/Rewrite.php

But not sure if I am in the right location for such requirements.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort this issue out. All I did was extend the /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Url/Rewrite.php file.

So I overode the loadByRequestPath function to serve the request in the current store, if not found, get a list of all the other available stores, loop through and find if the item exists. If found redirect to the store in which the URL key exists for the product and whola.

If none of the stores have it THEN return the 404 error.

And for static pages, the URL rewrite manager will be able to sort out the issue for you when you switch stores/languages.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Can you please add the looping code for your loadByRequestPath function?

Comment: would you like to share the code please as I am having similar issue with 5+ stores in same magento install.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mine is the most elegant of the solutions but I will post it anyway as it worked for me.
Basically I am searching in all stores the path that I am looking for in stead of only the specified store. Any suggestion would be more than welcome.

My config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <global>
  <modules>
    <Soipo_UrlRewrite>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </Soipo_UrlRewrite>
  </modules>
  <models>
    <soipo_urlrewrite>
        <class>Soipo_UrlRewrite_Model</class>
    </soipo_urlrewrite>
    <core_mysql4>
        <rewrite>
            <url_rewrite>Soipo_UrlRewrite_Model_Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Url_Rewrite</url_rewrite>
        </rewrite>
    </core_mysql4>
  </models>
 </global>
</config>
```

Rewrite.php

```
<?php
class Soipo_UrlRewrite_Model_Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Url_Rewrite extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Url_Rewrite{

/**
 * This function get an array of store ids, containing the Admin store.
 * @return array
 */
public function getStoreIds(){
    $allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
    $storeIds = array();
    $storeIds[] = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
    foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val)
    {
        $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
        $storeIds[] = $_storeId;
    }
    return $storeIds;
}

/**
 * Load rewrite information for request
 * If $path is array - we must load all possible records and choose one matching earlier record in array
 *
 * @param   Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite $object
 * @param   array|string $path
 * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Url_Rewrite
 */
public function loadByRequestPath(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite $object, $path)
{

    if (!is_array($path)) {
        $path = array($path);
    }

    $pathBind = array();
    foreach ($path as $key => $url) {
        $pathBind['path' . $key] = $url;
    }

    $storeIds = $this->getStoreIds();


    // Form select
    $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $select  = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where('request_path IN (:' . implode(', :', array_flip($pathBind)) . ')')
        ->where('store_id IN(?)', $storeIds);

    $items = $adapter->fetchAll($select, $pathBind);


    // Go through all found records and choose one with lowest penalty - earlier path in array, concrete store
    $mapPenalty = array_flip(array_values($path)); // we got mapping array(path => index), lower index - better
    $currentPenalty = null;
    $foundItem = null;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!array_key_exists($item['request_path'], $mapPenalty)) {
            continue;
        }
        $penalty = $mapPenalty[$item['request_path']] << 1 + ($item['store_id'] ? 0 : 1);
        if (!$foundItem || $currentPenalty > $penalty) {
            $foundItem = $item;
            $currentPenalty = $penalty;
            if (!$currentPenalty) {

                break; // Found best matching item with zero penalty, no reason to continue
            }
        }
    }

    // Set data and finish loading
    if ($foundItem) {
        $object->setData($foundItem);
    }

    // Finish
    $this->unserializeFields($object);
    $this->_afterLoad($object);

    return $this;
}


}
```